# How to make sprockets (or rack, or nginx?) motivate browsers to cache fonts and correctly return 304?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, browser-cache, cache-control, sprockets, rails-sprockets

In a Rails6 app with [webpacker replaced by sprockets](https://github.com/econya/yosis/commit/033656121a44b25351afb4943bf4bff0bad90352), I do not manage to let sprockets make my browser cache fonts. **Edit:** my browser does cache the font, but google complains and curl shows how the App responds (not as expected with a **304**, see below).

**Update**

It seems that a `304` is only returned when you tell the server (via `If-Modified-Since`-headers) that you know exactly the last modified version. While I Mozillas Dev Resources do not state that this should clearly be the case (and I am not in RFC-reading mood), it might make sens:

- your server serves the asset on 2020-01-01 (appreviated date for simplicity)
- a browser visits you and stores the asset alongside its date
- next day same browser revisits, asks server for asset and tells it the last known date (`2020-01-01` via `If-Modified-Since`-header)

  - server answes `304`: You know that stuff already
- next day a mistake happens and a dev-asset is served by the server
- browser revisits, gets new (but wrong asset with `Last modified` date of 2020-01-03) and stores it alongside that date
- server admins remove the wrong dev asset
- next day, browser visits and tells server "I know the thing from yesterday"

  - server tells browser: no, forgot that, the correct payload is this, and this is the timestamp: 2020-01-01.

In my tests below, I used `If-Modified-Since` headers that did not correspond to the last (production) asset Timestamp. Thanks @bliof for help figuring that out.

As my ultimate goal was to make googles speed insight happy (now that I know that this 304- response works if all players behave well) I will follow Rails 5+ path of `config.public_file_server.headers` (https://blog.bigbinary.com/2015/10/31/rails-5-allows-setting-custom-http-headers-for-assets.html). The Rails guides also point out how you would usually let your webserver (or CDN) handle the situation (https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#in-production), but my stack works somewhat different.

**Original follows**

The fonts are in e.g. `app/assets/fonts/OTF/SourceSansPro-BoldIt.otf` and correctly put in `public/assets/OTF/...fingerprint...` (accompanied by a **.gz** variant). They are referenced via a SCSS font-face rule, pointing to a file with the respective fingerprint in it (using `font-url()`).

When `curl`ing these, I seem to never get a `HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified`, but a `200` with the given payload. With the other (JS, CSS) assets it works as expected.

I did not modify `config/initializers/assets.rb`, as all the subdirectories and files should already be picked up (and the `assets:precompile` output and content of `public/assets` shows that it works).

Digging into the sprockets code at https://github.com/rails/sprockets/blob/9909da64595ddcfa1e7ee40ed1d99738961288ec/lib/sprockets/server.rb#L73 seems to indicate that maybe an etag is not set correctly or something like that, but I do not really grock that code.

The application is deployed with dokku (basically a heroku) with a pretty standard nginx-configuration as far as I can tell: https://github.com/dokku/dokku/blob/master/plugins/nginx-vhosts/templates/nginx.conf.sigil . The app serves the assets itself (like in heroku).

What do I have to do such that sprockets adds the relevant headers / responds "correctly" with a `304`? Any ideas how to debug that issue?

### The relevant "debugging" parts

#### The initial request for CSS

```
curl -v https://...application-3d...c76c3.css \
  -H 'Accept: text/css,*/*;q=0.1'\
  -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5'\
  --compressed # omitted: ... User-Agent, DNT, ...
# omitted: TLS handshake etc
> GET /assets/application-3d...c76c3.css HTTP/1.1
> Host: #the host
> Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0
> Accept: text/css,*/*;q=0.1
> Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
> Referer: #the host
> DNT: 1
> Connection: keep-alive
> Cookie: #a cookie
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx
< Date: Tue, 21 Apr 2020 15:39:47 GMT
< Content-Type: text/css
< Content-Length: 41256
< Connection: keep-alive
< Last-Modified: Mon, 06 Apr 2020 11:59:56 GMT
< Content-Encoding: gzip
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< 
# payload
```

#### Subsequent fetch of CSS

(The relevant parts, other params and output omitted).
Note that a **If-Modified-Since: Mon, 06 Apr 2020 11:59:56 GMT** header is sent along.

```
curl -v 'https://.../assets/application-3d...c76c3.css' \
  -H 'If-Modified-Since: Mon, 06 Apr 2020 11:59:56 GMT'\
  -H 'Cache-Control: max-age=0'
> If-Modified-Since: Mon, 06 Apr 2020 11:59:56 GMT
> Cache-Control: max-age=0
> 
< HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
< Server: nginx
< Date: Tue, 21 Apr 2020 15:50:52 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
```

(Thats what I want: A **304 Not Modified**.

#### The initial request for the font asset

```
curl -v 'https://.../assets/WOFF2/TTF/SourceSansPro-Light.ttf-32...d9.woff2' \
  -H 'Accept: application/font-woff2;q=1.0,application/font-woff;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'\
  -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5'\
  --compressed \
  -H 'Referer: https://...assets/application-3d....c76c3.css'
  # ommitted: User Agent, Cookies, ....
> GET /assets/WOFF2/TTF/SourceSansPro-Light.ttf-32...d9.woff2 HTTP/1.1
> Host: #the host
> Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0
> Accept: application/font-woff2;q=1.0,application/font-woff;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
> Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
> DNT: 1
> Connection: keep-alive
> Referer: https://.../assets/application-3d...c76c3.css
# cookie etc
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx
< Date: Tue, 21 Apr 2020 15:45:34 GMT
< Content-Type: application/font-woff2
< Content-Length: 88732
< Connection: keep-alive
< Last-Modified: Wed, 25 Mar 2020 20:09:14 GMT
< 
# payload
```

#### Subsequent fetch of Font

```
curl -v 'https://.../assets/WOFF2/TTF/SourceSansPro-Light.ttf-32...ed9.woff2' \
  -H 'Referer: https://.../assets/application-3d...c76c3.css'\
  -H 'If-Modified-Since: Mon, 06 Apr 2020 11:59:56 GMT'
  -H 'Cache-Control: max-age=0'
# ....
> If-Modified-Since: Mon, 06 Apr 2020 11:59:56 GMT
> Cache-Control: max-age=0
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx
< Date: Tue, 21 Apr 2020 15:53:46 GMT
< Content-Type: application/font-woff2
< Content-Length: 88732
< Connection: keep-alive
< Last-Modified: Wed, 25 Mar 2020 20:09:14 GMT
# payload
```

What I find interesting, that the server actually sends a **Last-Modified** which is way before the **If-Modified-Since**. I guess clever browsers stop the conversation there, but I really want to see a well-behaved 304.

Answer (score 1):

Here are few notes/findings:

---

It seems that it returns 304 when you match the timestamp.

In your example if you do the curl to the font with

```
-H 'If-Modified-Since: Wed, 25 Mar 2020 20:09:14 GMT'
```

You'll get the `HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified`

Same thing for the `.css` if you don't exactly match the date, you'll get 200.

---

I've tried changing sprockets locally to add some `puts` calls and also to change the default log level of sprockets itself but nothing happens.

TBO I don't believe the Sprokets::Server#call is getting called.

---

I've tried with `puma` and with `thin`, both return 304 only when the dates match.

---

```
curl --compressed -H 'Cache-Control: max-age=0' -H 'If-Modified-Since: Thu, 23 Apr 2020 21:34:30 GMT' -v http://localhost:3000/assets/OTF/SpaceMeatball-d61519ff17fadd38b57e3698067894c0e75fcb6031ee91034f5f7d6f2daa4d4b.otf

> Cache-Control: max-age=0
> If-Modified-Since: Thu, 23 Apr 2020 21:34:30 GMT
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Last-Modified: Thu, 23 Apr 2020 21:34:29 GMT

curl --compressed -H 'Cache-Control: max-age=0' -H 'If-Modified-Since: Thu, 23 Apr 2020 21:34:29 GMT' -v http://localhost:3000/assets/OTF/SpaceMeatball-d61519ff17fadd38b57e3698067894c0e75fcb6031ee91034f5f7d6f2daa4d4b.otf

> Cache-Control: max-age=0
> If-Modified-Since: Thu, 23 Apr 2020 21:34:29 GMT
>
< HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
```

I am running rails like this:

```
RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES=1 RAILS_ENV=production ./bin/rails s
or 
RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES=1 RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec thin start
```

todo - find what exactly is returning the response :)

Comment: Yeah I tried puts-debugging at various call methods in sprockets, too. STDOUT is likely suppressed, so I also `File.write('/tmp/debug.txt', 'mymsg')`-debugged and I agree: it seems that other middleware is handling the request (rack itself?).

Comment: <del>But do you agree that there should be a 304 if last-modified is "older" than "if-modified-since"? There is a bug, right? Or do I completely misunderstand something?</del> Ah, thinking about it it makes sense that the query is done with the exact timestamp. I will investigate, but most likely this will take some time.

Comment: Here you go with the bounty. While the rails guides say it is the Sprocket Middleware, I think it is `ActionDispatch::Static` (maybe thats actually the same thing, didnt check). As I might conquer more territory, I will not yet mark your answer as accepted but might make a write-up from what I edited to the question. Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, I've been busy lately. I'll try at some point to double check / update my answer ⏳ - it is quite an interesting question :) 

Otherwise there is a since in the name :D and the rfc has  "modification date being more recent than the date provided" and so on. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7232#section-3.3 tbo the current situation feels like a hacky way to accomplish 80-90% of the task.

Comment: Not sure if you have seen that I also updated my question. At least the PageSpeed Insight Google thing is happy if you set the headers, but nonetheless, I am also confused and hope to find the time to revisit the situation, also just to understand where the response is actually generated. Thanks so far.